# Location tracking via Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook API allows someone to continuously monitor the locations of all it's APAC users? Can I continuously fetch the locations using the API?

Comment: No, they don't. And the `location` field you can fetch via API, is what the user has _set_ on their profile as their current location, it isn't anything "live" that would automatically update.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe ... Any idea about any other app API? Google? Instagram?